# What is the regex required to find specific urls within content from a list of urls generated by a for loop?

Tags: regex, for-loop, python-2.7, urllib2

As I write this I realise there are two parts to this question, however I think I am only really stuck on the first part and therefore the second is only provided for context:

**Part A:**

I need to search the contents of each value returned by a for loop (where each value is a url) for the following:

`href="/dir/Sub_Dir/dir/163472311232-text-text-text-text/page-n"`

where:

- the numerals `163472311232` could be any length (ie it could be `5478`)
- `-text-text-text-text` could be any number of different words
- where `page-n` could be from `page-2` up until any number
- where matches are not returned more than once, ie only unique matches are returned and therefore only one of the following would be returned:

`href="/dir/Sub_Dir/dir/5422-la-la/page-4`

`href="/dir/Sub_Dir/dir/5422-la-la/page-4`

**Part B:**

So the logic would be something like:

```
list_of_urls = original_list
for url in list_of_urls:
    headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla 5.0'}
    request = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
    url_for_re = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    another_url = re.findall(r'href="(/dir/Sub_dir\/dir/[^"/]*)"', url_for_re, re.I)
    file.write(url)
    file.write('\n')
    file.write(another_url)
    file.write('\n')
```

Which i am hoping will give me output similar to:

```
a.html
a/page-2.html
a/page-3.html
a/page-4.html
b.html
b/page-2.html
b/page-3.html
b/page-4.html
```

So my question is (assuming the logic in part B is ok):

What is the required regex pattern to use for part A?

I am a newbie to python and regex so this will limit my understanding somewhat in regards to relatively complicated regex suggestions etc.

**update:**

after suggestions i tried to test the following regex which did not produce any results:

```
import re
content = 'href="/dir/Sub_Dir/dir/5648342378-text-texttttt-texty-text-text/page-2"'
matches = re.findall(r'href="/dir/Sub_Dir/dir/[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+/page-([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)"', content, re.I)
prefix = 'http://www.test.com'
for match in matches:
    i = prefix + match + '\n'
    print i
```

**solution:**

i think this is the regex that will work:

`matches = re.findall(r'href="(/dir/Sub_Dir/dir/[^"/]*/page-[2-9])"', content, re.I)`

Answer (score 0):

You can have... most of what you want. Regexes don't really do the distinct thing, so I suggest you just use them to get all the URLs, and then remove duplicates yourself.

Off the top of my head it would be something like this:
href="/dir/Sub_Dir/dir/[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+/page-([2-9])|([1-9][0-9]+)"

Plus or minus escaping rules, specifics on what words are allowed, etc. I'm a Windows guy, there's a great tool called Expresso which is helpful for learning regexes. I hope there's an equivalent for whatever platform you're using, it comes in handy.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  There's an error at the end of your regex; `page-([2-9])|([1-9][0-9]+)` should be `page-([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)`.  Errors like that are much easier to spot when you make use of this site's excellent [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) capabilities. ;)

Comment: i tried to test this regex but was unable to produce any matches from it.  test code was added to original post.

Comment: update:  i think i figured out a solution, added to original post.